# Replacing an array with specific id?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, replace

I have this Array:

```
Array
(
    [cart] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [size] => XS
                    [count] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [size] => XS
                    [count] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

How can I replace the array with id 2 in this multidimensional array for example?

I'm building an online-shop-system and want to add T-Shirts to a cart. If an article that already have been added would be added again, it should replace the cart-session-variable with the new input (new size, new count).

And how can I check if an specific id has already been added?

Comment: As I said: With new content like new size, new count, but same id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since every product has its own unique id you could use the product id as the index in the array, then you would be able to do something like this:

```
// pseudo code
function add2Cart($product_id, $count, $size) {
   global $cart;
   $cart[$product_id] = array(
      'count' => $count,
      'size' => $size
   );
)
```

Then you would have an array looking like:

```
[cart] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [size] => XS
                [count] => 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [size] => XS
                [count] => 1
            )

    )
```

Where each index is a products id number.

Comment: Global! And he is not using the id as key

Comment: Like I said it's only pseudo code to give him an idea on how to proceed. Also, I said that he **could** use the product id as a key.

Comment: What would it look like if I use the id as a key?

Comment: @KristerAndersson don't use globals this is not a good practice at all! You are teaching, please use good practices

Comment: @mcuadros - It doesn't seem like you read my post? I wanted to show that one approach would be to use the products id numbers as indexes. I also wrote `pseudo` code over my example. And I don't think stackoverflow is about writing code for others. And of course you shouldn't use `global` as in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

Given $cart with n products and $article as new an article to add:

```
$c = count($cart);
for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++) {
    if ($cart[$i]['id'] == $article['id']) {
        $cart[$i] = $article;
    }
}
```

If u use the product_id as key just

```
if (isset($cart[$article['id']]) {
    $cart[$article['id']] = $article;
}
```

Comment: First I've to check if an specific id is in the array. Do I have to do this foreach-loop or can I check it simplier?

Comment: You must foreach yes, or you must set the id as key of the array, and then just make array_key_exists or a simply isset

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what your looking for but I think this will do it.

```
foreach ($array['cart'] as &$item) {
    if ($item['id'] == $_POST['id']) {
        $item = $_POST;
    }
} unset($item);
```

Comment: First I've to check if an specific id is in the array. Do I have to do this foreach-loop or can I check it simplier?

Comment: This is probably the easiest way if you need to modify it too.

Comment: why you `unset($item);`

Comment: To release the reference created by `&$item`. Php doesn't automatically destroy it. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php